# Is there a program for controlling your audio volume with keys?

Tags: sound, games, volume-control

I am looking for a way to adjust my audio in different applications while playing games. For example, I play a lot of Rainbow six sieges and I would like to be able to control how loud my friends are on discord without tapping out of the game.

Is there any tool that would let me do so?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? There used to be one when Unity was the DE but I need to know which version you are running to search for it. Please click [edit] and advise which version of Ubuntu is in use, and if you changed the Desktop Environment after installation, what DE you're using. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, click [edit].

Answer (score 0):

No such hotkey is listed at either https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts 
Therefore, I bought a $10 used *multimedia* keyboard with dedicated volume keys (see picture).

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 or later you can use [GNOME Volume Mixer](https://github.com/aleho/gnome-shell-volume-mixer), a [GNOME Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1036/extensions/).

[image: picture].

Comment: not sure what you mean with this comment but thx you for trying

Comment: No such hotkey is listed at https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts . Because there wasn't, I suggested a keyboard with a volume control.

Comment: some ideas . I am 19.04     - if you have the top bar showing in your app, then a gnome tweak volume scroll (I have not used it) has volume control by scrolling top bar, then should could set keyboard shortcuts to do that using  something like 'xdotool mousemove  --sync  $xcoords 10 --screen $primaryscreen ' and then activate the scroll wheel. that said, it would muck up the game probably.  https://extensions.gnome.org/#             https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1420/volume-scroll/